# Media Server on ubuntu

Tags: server, gui, media

I had an extra laptop in my cupboard for a few months now and yesterday my friend told me that I could store my films on the laptop and set up a media server on ubuntu using the laptop instead of going through the trouble of transferring media files from my other laptop (runs windows) to my phone. How can I setup a media server so i can easily play and watch them on my mobile.